# Unable to launch OS X Mountain Lion VM on VMWare

Tags: virtual-machine, osx-mountain-lion, vmware-workstation, vmdk

I have OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.3 which was running fine up till yesterday. But today, when I tried to launch the same via VMWare Workstation, it is not going past the Apple Logo with activity indicator.

I am using **VMWare Workstation 8**.

**I tried:**

1. Launching the OS X VM on VMWare 9
2. Checked the smc.present state of .vmx file which is "FALSE".
3. Checked the following:

   ```
   scsi0:0.present = "TRUE"
   scsi0:0.fileName = "OS X Mountain Lion.vmdk".
   ```

I am still stuck at the same screen.

**Here's my complete .vmx file:**

```
.encoding = "windows-1252"
config.version = "8"
virtualHW.version = "8"
scsi0.present = "TRUE"
scsi0.virtualDev = "lsilogic"
memsize = "4096"
scsi0:0.present = "TRUE"
scsi0:0.fileName = "OS X Mountain Lion.vmdk"
ide1:0.present = "TRUE"
ide1:0.autodetect = "TRUE"
ide1:0.deviceType = "cdrom-raw"
floppy0.startConnected = "FALSE"
floppy0.fileName = ""
floppy0.autodetect = "TRUE"
ethernet0.present = "TRUE"
ethernet0.connectionType = "bridged"
ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000"
ethernet0.wakeOnPcktRcv = "FALSE"
ethernet0.addressType = "generated"
usb.present = "TRUE"
ehci.present = "TRUE"
sound.present = "TRUE"
sound.virtualDev = "hdaudio"
sound.fileName = "Headphones (High Definition Aud"
sound.autodetect = "FALSE"
pciBridge0.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge4.functions = "8"
pciBridge5.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge5.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge5.functions = "8"
pciBridge6.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge6.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge6.functions = "8"
pciBridge7.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge7.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge7.functions = "8"
vmci0.present = "TRUE"
hpet0.present = "TRUE"
ich7m.present = "TRUE"
usb.vbluetooth.startConnected = "TRUE"
firmware = "efi"
displayName = "OS X Mountain Lion"
guestOS = "darwin11-64"
nvram = "OS X Mountain Lion.nvram"
virtualHW.productCompatibility = "hosted"
powerType.powerOff = "hard"
powerType.powerOn = "hard"
powerType.suspend = "hard"
powerType.reset = "hard"
extendedConfigFile = "OS X Mountain Lion.vmxf"
ethernet0.generatedAddress = "00:0C:29:EB:95:D8"
vmci0.id = "44668943"
uuid.location = "56 4d 4a 9e c5 11 a0 d3-0f c6 51 f3 8a eb 95 d8"
uuid.bios = "56 4d 4a 9e c5 11 a0 d3-0f c6 51 f3 8a eb 95 d8"
cleanShutdown = "TRUE"
replay.supported = "FALSE"
replay.filename = ""
scsi0:0.redo = ""
pciBridge0.pciSlotNumber = "17"
pciBridge4.pciSlotNumber = "21"
pciBridge5.pciSlotNumber = "22"
pciBridge6.pciSlotNumber = "23"
pciBridge7.pciSlotNumber = "24"
scsi0.pciSlotNumber = "16"
usb.pciSlotNumber = "32"
ethernet0.pciSlotNumber = "33"
sound.pciSlotNumber = "34"
ehci.pciSlotNumber = "35"
vmci0.pciSlotNumber = "36"
usb:1.present = "TRUE"
ethernet0.generatedAddressOffset = "0"
vmotion.checkpointFBSize = "134217728"
usb:1.speed = "2"
usb:1.deviceType = "hub"
usb:1.port = "1"
usb:1.parent = "-1"
annotation = "      OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.2 Image|0D|0A-------------------------------------------|0D|0A             Courtesy of ZackehSoul|0D|0A-------------------------------------------|0D|0A|0D|0A- For instructions visit the link in the downloaded folder.|0D|0A- Includes iMessage fix .vmx, see readme.|0D|0A- Based on Mountain Lion Retail as of 25/09.|0D|0A- If you need to contact me quickly, you can find me here; http://q.gs/wQNX|0D|0A- You can also email me at zackehsoul@hotmail.co.uk, or find me on http://souldevteam.net."
numvcpus = "4"
cpuid.coresPerSocket = "2"
ide1:0.fileName = "auto detect"
mks.enable3d = "TRUE"
usb.autoConnect.device0 = ""
checkpoint.vmState = ""
tools.syncTime = "FALSE"
gui.lastPoweredViewMode = "fullscreen"
gui.viewModeAtPowerOn = "fullscreen"
tools.remindInstall = "FALSE"
usb.autoConnect.device1 = ""
ethernet0.linkStatePropagation.enable = "TRUE"
tools.upgrade.policy = "upgradeAtPowerCycle"
svga.autodetect = "FALSE"
svga.maxWidth = "1280"
svga.maxHeight = "800"
svga.vramSize = "134217728"
ide1:0.startConnected = "FALSE"
isolation.tools.hgfs.disable = "TRUE"
sharedFolder.maxNum = "1"
sharedFolder0.present = "TRUE"
sharedFolder0.enabled = "TRUE"
sharedFolder0.readAccess = "TRUE"
sharedFolder0.writeAccess = "TRUE"
sharedFolder0.hostPath = "D:\MyData"
sharedFolder0.guestName = "MyData"
sharedFolder0.expiration = "never"
monitor.virtual_mmu = "software"
monitor.virtual_exec = "software"
vhv.enable = "TRUE"
disable_acceleration = "TRUE"
smc.present = "FALSE"
scsi0:1.present = "FALSE"
softPowerOff = "FALSE"
usb:0.present = "TRUE"
usb:0.deviceType = "hid"
usb:0.port = "0"
usb:0.parent = "-1"
```

**System Config:**

Windows 8
Core i5 2.3 GHz
8 GB RAM (4 GB dedicated to VM)
500GB HDD (265 GB dedicated to VM)
Size of .vmdk file: 123 GB

**Queries**

1. Is there any way to extract the data of .vmdk file on to my system ?
2. Can I run the existing .vmdk file on MAC OS Mavericks VM ?

Comment: You say you had 10.8 running until yesterday. In a VM?

Comment: I had 10.8.2. Then I upgraded it to 10.8.5 using the patch which enables to download XCode5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was able to resolve the issue by simply restoring my host machine to previous state.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Snapshots! VM heaven! Mess everything up, and simply go back, unless of course you haven't got any...

Comment: OP did not use VMware snapshots. He restored his *host* system to a previous state (probably using Windows System Restore).